# Solution for draw a shortest path to navigate between many markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on google maps and I need to draw the shortest path to navigate and visit all markers selected by the user.

I make my algorithm to solve that but the solution takes a long time and many codding, I need to know If there is any API or method to solve that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Google API, maybe consider using Google Directions API.
You can provide it with a start and end locations and up to 20+ locations and the API will calculate the best route.

You can find more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/routes/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_397052992493-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20~%20Routes%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Directions%20API-KWID_43700049595992169-kwd-445998650286-userloc_1008006&utm_term=KW_%2Bdirections%20%2Bapi-ST_%2Bdirections%20%2Bapi&gclid=Cj0KCQiAs67yBRC7ARIsAF49CdXs7Ct2Em8Hw1749wVBwQcwFUZonYgx-VBmsdyO1zLvtD3fsyH_a_oaAtgBEALw_wcB).

Hope this helps.